# Where to initialize Socket object in React Containers?

Tags: javascript, sockets, reactjs, mern

I am working on  React.js and socket.io.
My application consists of multiple containers.Each container has components.

My container and component hierarchy

- Dashboard
- Chat

  - ChatListItem
  - CustomerChatView

So here Dashboard and Chat are two separate containers defined in separate js files.
I want to share websocket object between Dashboard and Chat message,so that dashboard will be able to show alert message to user when there is a new chat message in Chat Container.

My question is what is the most appropriate place to initialize websocket so that the same socket object can be used in both containers?

I am using socket.io javascript library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably create a root app container which can dispatch an action on componentWillMount to initialize the socket and store the result in the store. Then you can pass it to any other container and use it wherever necessary.

Comment: On second thought I would probably still initialize the socket in componentWillMount, but I would store the reference in a separate dedicated module that perhaps only exposed an API to work with it. Your store state is supposed to be serializable and storing a socket in there would likely make it not so.